# Shall we continue to pray during sun rise / set?

Tags: salat, hadith-interpretation, time

Assalam,

It is a widely known fact that there is no prayer during sun rise and sun set as [Shaitan accompanies those times](https://sunnah.com/urn/1286010).

> Allah's Apostle said, "If anyone of you can get one Rak'a of the 'Asr prayer before sunset, he should complete his prayer. If any of you can get one Rak'a of the Fajr prayer before sunrise, he should complete his prayer." ([Source](http://ahadith.co.uk/permalink-hadith-1608))

We are aware that Asr ([middle prayer](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=238)) is a very important Salah and [missing it costs a lot](http://ahadith.co.uk/permalink-hadith-7759).

**So, how has to be the quoted Hadith understood? If we start our prayer before sunset, shall we continue praying even during the sun set?**

Jakallahu Khairan.

Comment: You are asked to catch up your fard prayers at any time, but do not add optional prayers in a time of karaha.

Comment: Assalam, @Medi1Saif can you point to any scholarly resources that say that we can initiate our prayers at ANY time?

Comment: At the moment I'm only using my mobile phone therefore my activity is limitted.

Comment: @Medi1Saif what do you mean by "catch-up"? i thought we should make kaza if time is passed.

Comment: @qdinar see the answer if M.M.

Comment: @Medi1Saif so if prayer which is forgotten is prayed immediately when it is remembered, can be prayed at that time not as kaza but with niyah phrase as regularly / usually? - i did not know...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple...

1. Initiating a Nafl prayer in the times you mentioned is impermissible(I will not go into details since it is out of your question's scope).
2. Obligatory (FARD) prayer is not included in that because of other Hadith:

> He who forgets the prayer should perform it when he remembers it, there is
> no penance for it, except this. Qatada said: (Allah says)" And
> observe prayer for remembrance of Me"
> [Sahih Muslim 684 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:684a)

And Also if you read the scholars' explanations you will notice all mentions the Nafl prayers.

---

Note: I manipulated the translation to be clear.

Note2: the reason for not praying at that time (initiating the prayer at that time) is to not do like the disbelievers of those who worship the sun:

> ...Observe the dawn prayer, then stop praying when the sun is rising till
> it is fully up, for when it rises it comes up between the horns of
> Satan, and the unbelievers prostrate themselves to it at that time...

Part of long Hadith  [Sahih Muslim 832](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/358)

Comment: "He who forgets the prayer should perform it when he remembers it, there is no penance for it, except this. Qatada said: (Allah says)" And observe prayer for remembrance of Me"" I'm afraid you've misused this Hadith to say that you can initiate the salah (any) when the sun has started rising. I think it is wrong. I think acc, to Hadith I quoted, you can initiate only before sun has started rising  setting.

Comment: Please if possible point to the articles by scholars.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser he says " in the times you mentioned ... Obligatory ... prayer is not included in that ", so i think he does not say to initiate prayer after sun appeared, but only about when you can make 1 rak'a before that.

Answer (score -1):

i interpret

> The sun rises between the two horns of Satan

and

> The two horns of Satan rise with it, and when it has risen, Satan
>   parts from it. When it is in the middle of the sky he accompanies it,
>   then ...

this way:

sun rises between hills and mountains at horizon, for that, position of sun at sunrise an sunset points is not enough ideally defined. also, when it is at zenith, we cannot be sure about it, when exactly it is. for that reason, this ideal positions should not be used to plan prayer at them. because if anybody wants to do that he cannot surely do it. but nowadays people can use clock and [stellarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarium_(software)) and {map or gps} to know exact, nearly second-precise time of zenith. but even if it is second-precise we cannot start prayer exactly at zenith, but can only start it before it, or after it surely.

and i interpret

> So do no pray at these three times

this way:

https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/190 :

> Abu Huraira (Allah be pleased with him) reported Allah's Apostle (ﷺ)
>   as saying: Do not single out the night (preceding) Friday among the
>   nights for prayer and do not single out Friday among days for fasting
>   but only when anyone among you is accustomed to fast (on dates) which
>   coincide with this day (Friday).

this hadith allows fasting at friday if it was planned not as fasting at friday while fasting in friday denied in other hadiths:

https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/8/62 :

> Abu Hurairah narrated that : the Messenger of Allah said: "None of you
>   should fast on Friday unless he fasts before it, or he fasts after
>   it."

so , the last hadith does not mean that fasting on friday alone is prohibited, but it means that it is prohibited to plan to do it on friday alone, binding directly with friday, for example as "this friday", or "every friday".

i think, if you already was late for fajr or asr prayer for several consecutive days, making it in its latest possible time as said in the hadith, maybe you should not continue to do so in next day if you again are so much late, because it becomes like if you pray it by intention in that time... in other hand, it is not your intention... also there is rule that little sin becomes big sin if done continuously... in other hand, refusing to pray fard prayer in the latest possible time, while it is possible and allowed by hadith, and leaving it to be prayed as kaza, is even more sin... in other hand, maybe making prayer many consecutive days at the prohibited times is itself a bigger sin.